# How to adjust laptop screen colour

Tags: resolution, screen-printing

Hello I recently purchased a hp gaming laptop, I am ok with the way the laptop is except the screen colour which I would like to make it look like the current hp pavilion G6 am using. So in short I want the screen colour of my hp gaming laptop to be like my hp pavilion G6.

Below is the screenshot of the desired hp pavilion G6

[image]

Below is the screen colour of my hp gaming laptop

[image]

Any idea or suggestions is highly welcomed.

Comment: Do you have access to a colorimeter?

Comment: Try using the "Calibrate Display Colour" software available in Windows 10. Maybe best to run it on both computers if you want them to be similar to each other.  Note that graphic designers generally use hardware calibration devices to  calibrate their monitors as these are much more accurate than software calibration. These devices aren't something most ordinary computer users would have access to however.